# 2d arrays, functions, C

Tags: c, 2d, max, arrays

The problem is to write a function that takes a 2 dimensional array, 2 integers which represent the number of rows and columns in the array, and prints out a 2 X 2 array which represents the largest square in the array. The largest square means the square for which the sum of its elements is the greatest in the array.

Given array: 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

output should be:

7 8

11 12

Though we never learned about subarray/matrixes and the kadane algorithm in class i've been online all day and im just hopping this is somewhat close to the solution? (*My professor is only interested in the function, we're not even supposed to submit a full program) it was due yesterday but Im so lost, please help if you can and thanks in advance!

```
/*Void f(x) that opens file to take in given array*/
void largestSqaure(int array[ROW][COLUMN])
{  

     FILE*ifp= fopen("largestSquare.txt", "r");
     FILE*ofp= fopen("output.txt", "w");
     for(R0W= 0; ROW < SIZE; ROW++)
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array[ROW]);

    /*Declaring variables*/
    int maxSum = INT_MIN, finalLeft, finalRight, finalTop, finalBottom;
    int left, right, i;
    int temp[ROW], sum, start, finish;

    /* Adding left and right columns & intiializing size in loop*/
    for (left = 0; left < COLUMN; ++left)
    {
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));

        for (right = left; right < COLUMN; ++right)
        {
            /* Calucalting sums for in between*/
            for (i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
                temp[i] += array[i][right];

            /* Finding the max subarray using kadane*/
            sum = kadane(temp, &start, &finish, ROW);

            if (sum > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = sum;
                finalLeft = left;
                finalRight = right;
                finalTop = start;
                finalBottom = finish;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Printing the 2 X 2 array that had max sum*/
    printf("%d, %d\n", finalTop, finalLeft);
    printf("d, %d\n", finalBottom, finalRight);

 system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Still unclear what the goal of the problem is from the way you worded it our how the input relates to the output. And why is the input array said to be two dimensions but shown on 3 lines?

Comment: I pretty much copied the question from our assignement page, and our professor doesnt discuss codes until after they're due (so next week) In her other sample input it was:                                                          Given the array                       8    2   6

                                               3     7    3

                                               6     1     1                                               the output should be              8          2
                                              3           7

Comment: This isn't really the kind of site that helps people decipher whole assignments and develop and debug code for solving problems, it's more for resolving focused technical questions, for example a bug or an area you're stuck in your code when you understand the goal and have done due diligence.  If you're confused about the goal no one here is going to  know. We didn't even attend the lecture.

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array[ROW]);` is wrong.

Comment: this code block: ' for(R0W= 0; ROW < SIZE; ROW++)
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array[ROW]);' is definately not correct as it puts only one integer in each ROW of an array and also only defines a single / scalar array, not a MxN matrix  suggest hardcoding the matrix in a 'int matrix[m][n]  = { {,,,},{....} ... };'  values so you can concentrate on the problem rather than the I/O

Comment: if you make the array relatively small, say 3x3, then you could put it on paper and walk through how you would calculate the max 2x2 sub matrix.  then just implement that walk through in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ROW    3
#define COLUMN 4

int main(void){
    int a[ROW][COLUMN] = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12}
    };
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int max_r, max_c;
    int r, c;
    for(r=0; r < ROW-1; ++r){
        for(c=0; c < COLUMN-1; ++c){
            int sum = a[r][c] + a[r][c+1] + a[r+1][c] + a[r+1][c+1];
            if(sum > max){
                max = sum;
                max_r = r;
                max_c = c;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", a[max_r][max_c], a[max_r][max_c+1]);
    printf("%d %d\n", a[max_r+1][max_c], a[max_r+1][max_c+1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is find the 2x2 grid in an nxm matrix such that your grid is the maximal 2x2 sub grid in the matrix.

So, a simple way would be to step through the nxm matrix inspecting all the 2x2 grids, and storing the maximal grid in a 2x2 answer array.

When n < 2 or m < 2, the result is undefined. When n=m=2, there is only one sub grid of dimension 2x2, and so you've found it. When n > 2 or m > 2, you will have some number x of 2x2 arrays within your nxm matrix.

```
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    for(j=0;j<m-1;j++){
        //is matrix m[i][j] ... m[i+1][j+1] greater
        //than my previous maximal 2x2
        //sub grid? If so update.
    }
}
```

The idea being you inspect all 2x2 sub grids in your nxm matrix and update your current maximum 2x2 grid if you find a larger one.

Comment: Thank you so much for an actual reply, i understand no one is here to write my code but I am beyond lost, and we are assigned everything online. Would you do that by simply using if statements?

Comment: Think it out in normal speech to yourself, and once you've figured out how you yourself would decide one grid is larger than another, write it down. Look at the process you wrote down, and think about how you could translate it into code. Then just give it a try, see what happens. I would think that if statements could definitely be employed here. I wouldn't worry about trying to find the optimal way to do it until you find _a_ way to do it. Good luck!